# Is there a way to read a file in C without a bunch of checks for sscanf and fgets?

Tags: c, string, input, scanf

In a program I'm writing, I'm currently doing the part of parsing an input file. I have to do input validation (to some degree), checking if `sscanf` parses the right number of variables and `fgets` isn't null. But as a result, the main outline looks like this:

```
int LINE_LENGTH = 100;
int parseInput(FILE* fp, FILE* output) {
    char* line = calloc(LINE_LENGTH, sizeof(char));
    if (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, fp) == NULL) return 1;
    int camFlag, lightFlag;
    if (sscanf(line, "%d %d %d\n", &frames, &camFlag, &lightFlag) != 3) return 1;
    if (camFlag) {
        if (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, fp) == NULL) return 1;
        double cx, cy, cz, dx, dy, dz, dt;
        if (sscanf(line, "%f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", &cx, &cy, &cz, &dx, &dy, &dz, &dt) != 7) return 1;
        // do stuff with input
    }
    if (lightFlag) {
        if (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, fp) == NULL) return 1;
        double cx, cy, cz;
        unsigned char r, g, b;
        if (sscanf(line, "%f %f %f %hhu %hhu %hhu\n", &cx, &cy, &cz, &r, &g, &b) != 6) return 1;
        // do stuff with this data
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
        if (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, fp) == NULL)) return 1;
        int n;
        if (sscanf(line, "%d\n", &n) != 1) return 1;
        // etc...
    }
}
```

and as a result, half the lines are checking input. Is there a good way to avoid this?

Comment: Every once in awhile, you can do better with helper functions and longjump, but typically I find it looks like this.

Comment: On an unrelated note, what is `LINE_LENGHT`? Doing that dynamic allocation will lead to memory leaks if the input validation fails. Why not use a plain array?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's just how I've always done it, I'll look into your way!

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really need those newline matches in `sscanf`. If you want to make sure that `fgets` reads the whole lines then check for the existence of newline in the buffer itself, not through `sscanf` (as it won't fail if it's missing).

Comment: The newline in your `sscanf()` *format-string* will ***never*** match. `'\n'` is whitespace -- and that causes `sscanf` to skip whitespace....

Answer (score 1):

Since you are following a pattern:

```
    if (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, fp) == NULL) return 1;
    int camFlag, lightFlag;
    if (sscanf(line, "%d %d %d\n", &frames, &camFlag, &lightFlag) != 3) return 1;
```

You could make your own function to combine the calls and checks of the `fgets` and `sscanf` functions into one, that way the code would be less verbose.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int LINE_LENGTH = 100;
int checked_fgets_sscanf(FILE *fp, int count, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    //char* line = calloc(LINE_LENGTH, sizeof(char));
    char line[LINE_LENGTH];
    if (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, fp) == NULL) return 1;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    int rc = vsscanf(line, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    //free(line);
    return rc != count;
}

int main()
{

    int a, b;
    if(checked_fgets_sscanf(stdin, 2, "%d %d", &a, &b)) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Where the parameter `count` of the function receives the number of variadic arguments used in the `sscanf` function.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to read a file in C without a bunch of checks for sscanf and fgets?

Yes. Just read characters one by one with `fgetc`, then apply usual [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques.

Read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).

Consider using [parser generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) such as [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/), [flex](https://www.gnu.org/software/flex/)+[bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison), [lemon](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/), etc... Then would generate some C code from a higher-level description of the parsed language.

Or else, if your input parsed language is weird enough, use your own meta-programming techniques. Write (perhaps in in some other programming language like [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Python](https://python.org/)) some [metaprogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) to generate the C code (perhaps some [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)) you are manually writing from a higher-level description. Then adapt your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) (e.g. add a few lines to your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)) for such cases.

Notice that **parsing is a well established technique**. You'll find research papers on parsing (and compiler building, and interpreter building) since the 1960s. **You'll find tons of [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) programs** (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com) or elsewhere) **whose parsing should be inspirational to you:** e.g. most C [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (e.g. [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler)), Unix [shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) such as [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [zsh](https://zsh.org/) or [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell), the source code of [Python](https://python.org/), etc...

Answer (score 0):

One of the good way to get data form the file is fscanf(). There is no need to use fgets or sscanf. You can use `while(fgetc(fp) != '\n');` for next line.

fscanf is use as sscanf but for the file. other rules are same.

please check the code I rewrite that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int LINE_LENGTH = 100;
int parseInput(FILE* fp, FILE* output) {
    char* line = calloc(LINE_LENGTH, sizeof(char));
    int camFlag, lightFlag, frames;
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &frames, &camFlag, &lightFlag) != 3) return 1;
    printf("frames - %d, camFlag - %d, lightFlag - %d\n", frames, camFlag, lightFlag);
    while(fgetc(fp) != '\n');
    if (camFlag) {
        double cx, cy, cz, dx, dy, dz, dt;
        if (fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", &cx, &cy, &cz, &dx, &dy, &dz, &dt) != 7) return 1;
        printf("cx - %lf, cy - %lf, cz - %lf, dx - %lf, dy - %lf, dz - %lf, dt - %lf\n", cx, cy, cz, dx, dy, dz, dt);
        while(fgetc(fp) != '\n');
        // do stuff with input
    }
    if (lightFlag) {
        double cx, cy, cz;
        unsigned char r, g, b;
        if (fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf %hhu %hhu %hhu", &cx, &cy, &cz, &r, &g, &b) != 6) return 1;
        printf("cx - %lf, cy - %lf, cz - %lf, r - %hhu, g - %hhu, b - %hhu\n",cx, cy, cz, r, g, b);
        while(fgetc(fp) != '\n');
        // do stuff with this data
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
        int n;
        if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &n) != 1) return 1;
        printf("n - %d\n", n);
        while(fgetc(fp) != '\n');
        // etc...
    }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        FILE * fp1 = NULL , * fp2 = NULL;
        fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        parseInput(fp1, fp2);

}
```

```
file data: 
1 2 3
1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7
1.1 2.2 3.3 4 5 6
1
```

```
OUTUPT:

frames - 1, camFlag - 2, lightFlag - 3
cx - 1.100000, cy - 2.200000, cz - 3.300000, dx - 4.400000, dy - 5.500000, dz - 6.600000, dt - 7.700000
cx - 1.100000, cy - 2.200000, cz - 3.300000, r - 4, g - 5, b - 6
n - 1
```